# Inclusion and orthogonality in a vector space

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification, orthogonality

Let $E$ be a $k$-vector space. Remember that for any subset $A\subset E$, the orthogonal of $A$ is defined as

$$A^{\perp}:=\{\lambda\in E^* | \forall x\in A, \lambda(x)=0\}$$

Now, let $F$ and $G$ be two subspaces of $E$. Of course, we have the implication $$F\subset G \implies G^{\perp}\subset F^{\perp}$$
but I am interested in the converse. Every reference I have only states the above implication without giving a word about the converse. I think I am able to show it, however I now have a doubt about the validity of my proof. Could someone please validate or tell me where I am wrong (aside from the fact that I am using the axiom of choice) ?

Thank you very much !

> $$G^{\perp}\subset F^{\perp} \implies F\subset G$$

**Proof:** Suppose $G^{\perp}\subset F^{\perp}$ and assume toward a contradiction that there exists some $x\in F\setminus G$. Consider a basis $\mathcal B$ of $G$. Then, the family $\mathcal B \cup \{x\}$ is still free, as $x$ does not lie in $G$. Hence, we may complete $\mathcal B \cup \{x\}$ into a basis $\{e_i\}_{i\in I}$ of $E$. Let us then rewrite $x=e_{i_0}$ and $\mathcal B = \{e_j\}_{j\in J}$ for some $i_0\in I$ and $J\subset I$. Naturally, $i_0\not \in J$.
Now that we have a basis, we may consider the dual family $\{e_i^*\}_{i\in I}$ in $E^*$ defined by the formulae $e_i^*(e_j)=\delta_{i,j}$.
Because $e_{i_0}^*(x)=1$, we see that $e_{i_0}^*\not \in F^{\perp}$. However, for every $j\in J$, we do have $e_{i_0}^*(e_j)=0$. As the family $\{e_j\}_{j\in J}$ is a basis of $G$, we see that $e_{i_0}^* \in G^{\perp}$.
This is absurd, and concludes the proof.

Comment: Yes, this is valid. Another way is to base on extending a functional (from a subspace to a superspace) and the fact that $\mathcal{B}\cup\{x\}$ is a basis of $G\oplus kx$ (so an extension of the functional $f$, defined on the latter by $f(ax + y) = a$, would produce the same contradiction). A matter of taste.

Comment: Thank you very much @metamorphy !